# Is it possible to represent any C-infinite function as some Maclaurin/Taylor series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, analytic-functions, smooth-functions

I have heard that the set of all functions $R \to R$ is more than uncountable, but the set of all continuous functions $R \to R$ is only uncountable.

If I reason correctly, the set of all Maclaurin series is uncountable, since the set of possible coefficients for each monomial is uncountable, while the set of monomials is countable, so the set of all possible polynomials is uncountable (the Cartesian product of a countable and uncountable set is uncountable).

However, not every continuous function is representable in Maclaurin series (any polynomial is C-infinite, while the set of all continuous functions is C-0). My question is: is every C-infinite function representable in Maclaurin series? If not, what's the name of the set of all functions $R \to R$ representable in Maclaurin series?

Comment: The standard example of a $C^\infty$ function that cannot be represented by a Maclaurin series is $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x}  & x>0, \\ 0 & x \leq 0 \end{cases}. $$ You can prove that it's smooth at $x=0$ and it's also smooth elsewhere. But it's Maclaurin series is the constant zero function, which is not equal to $f$. The class of functions representable at $p$ by the Taylor series about $p$ are called _real-analytic functions_ at $p$. And so the class of real analytic functions is strictly smaller than that of smooth functions.

Comment: Side note: it is not very meaningful to say "more than uncountable", because any set with any cardinality bigger than that of natural numbers, no matter how big, is considered uncountable. By "uncountable" you probably mean the cardinality of the reals, which is usually known as _the continuum_ denoted by $\mathfrak{c}$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to put an end to this question (see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) post as well on the issue), I just post my previous answer from the comments section; also feel free to ask further questions.

The standard example of a smooth function that cannot be represented by a Maclaurin series is

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x} & x>0, \\ 0 & x \leq 0 \end{cases}.$$

[It is provable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) that $f$ is smooth at $x=0$, and it's also clearly smooth elsewhere. But its Maclaurin series is the constant zero function, which is not equal to $f$. The class of functions representable at $p$ by the Taylor series about $p$ are called *real-analytic functions at $p$*. And so the class of real analytic functions is strictly smaller than that of smooth functions.